# How to get only first object in template?

Tags: python, django

views:

```
....
d = Data.objects.filter(is_accepted=True)
....
```

templates:

```
{% for item in d %}
    {% for picture in item.photo_set.all %}
        <img class="image" src="{{ picture.photo.url}}">
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

How to get only **first** photo? (`{{ picture.photo.url}}`)

Answer (score 3):

You can index with the dot notation:

```
{{ item.photo_set.all.0.photo.url }}
```

Comment: That's neater than my solution. +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `forloop.first`. Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

```
{% for item in d %}
    {% for picture in item.photo_set.all %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
            <img class="image" src="{{ picture.photo.url}}">
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, a sharp knife.

Second, a [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slice)